# Vue: Store state doesn't rendering in the app

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I declare an array in vue store, and when i call it in the app, it doesn't appear.
Please i'm beginner and i need help.

There is my store code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    Produits: [
            {text: "ananas", checked: true},
            {text: "banane", checked: false},
            {text: "orange", checked: true},
    ]
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

There is the component code:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="produit in products" :key="produit.id" v-bind:class="{ 'removed':produit.checked }">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label >
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="produit.checked"> {{produit.text}}
            </label>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>

export default ({
    computed: {
        products: function() {
            return this.$store.state.produits;
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't declared data in component code.

Answer (score 0):

Produits is not produits you can write always camelcase, so you don't get confused.